# Eloquent join table on date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, morris.js

Clicks table schema:

```
user_id as (integer)
created_at as (Y-m-d H:i:s)
```

Views table

```
user_id as (integer)
created_at as (Y-m-d H:i:s)
```

I need to count records in 1st table + 2nd table group by date NOT datetime:

Right now I am using 2 queries:

```
$clicks = $user->clicks()
->select(\DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d/%m/%Y') as date"),
        \DB::raw("COUNT(*) as clicks"))
->groupBy('date')
->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
->get()->toArray();

$views = $user->views()
->select(\DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d/%m/%Y') as date"),
    \DB::raw("COUNT(*) as views"))
->groupBy('date')
->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
->get()->toArray();
```

And after I have a loop

```
$out = [];
    for ($i=0; $i < count($views); $i++) { 
        $out[] = [
            'date' => $views[$i]['date'],
            'clicks' => $clicks[$i]['clicks'],
            'views' => $views[$i]['views']
        ];
    }
```

But this way if click exist and view no on some date it will not add it toarray
It is possible to join on created_at by date format? without time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since MySQL not supported full join try this

```
select date(clicks.created_at)as 'Date',
count(clicks.user_id) as 'clicks',
count(views.user_id)as 'views'
from clicks
left join views on date(views.created_at)=date(clicks.created_at)
group by date(clicks.created_at)

union

select date(views.created_at)as 'Date',
count(clicks.user_id) as 'clicks',
count(views.user_id)as 'views'
from views
left join clicks  on date(views.created_at)=date(clicks.created_at)
group by date(views.created_at)
```

since you have count in your query try the this query

```
select a.Date,a.clicks,b.views
 from(select date(clicks.created_at)as 'Date',
       count(clicks.user_id) as 'clicks'
       from clicks
       group by date(clicks.created_at))a
 left join (select date(views.created_at)as 'Date',
       count(views.user_id) as 'views'
       from views
       group by date(views.created_at))b
 on a.date=b.date    

union

select a.Date,b.clicks,a.views
 from(select date(views.created_at)as 'Date',
       count(views.user_id) as 'views'
       from views
       group by date(views.created_at))a
 left join (select date(clicks.created_at)as 'Date',
       count(clicks.user_id) as 'clicks'
       from clicks
       group by date(clicks.created_at))b
 on a.date=b.date
```

Comment: Hmm tried on NaviCat the output is wrong took only one date twice and count is +400 but I have only 8))

Comment: change the user_id to *, maybe you have null values, and make sure you put group by in boat of the queries, i forgot to put group by in the second query

Comment: Yes I tried to add to both groupBy and change the user_id to * still the same

Comment: i've added second query , try it know pls

Comment: Unknown column 'b.views' in 'field list'

Comment: Works, how can I add now a where user_id = value

Comment: after each from or after the join condition ( above the union and in the last row

Comment: Ok works now need to set order))) and translate it to eloquent